# Can R-3-methyl-4-heptanone be enantioselectively synthesised from 4-heptanone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, enolate-chemistry

I wonder if it is possible to do the following reaction with its enantioselectivity:

[image: Enantioselective synthesis of R-3-methyl-4-heptanone]

I am trying to do it via enolate, but I don't know how to make only the R product or if it's even possible to distinguish between R or S simply using enolates.

There's another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Enders SAMP/RAMP hydrazone chemistry will do this(1).

[The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enders_SAMP/RAMP_hydrazone-alkylation_reaction) on this technique is a good introduction:

[image]

(1): Corey, E. J.; Enders, D. (**1976**). "Applications of N,N-dimethylhydrazones to synthesis. Use in efficient, positionally and stereochemically selective C-C bond formation; oxidative hydrolysis to carbonyl compounds". Tetrahedron Letters. 17 (1): 3–6.